# How to use *ngFor below mentioned attached image

Tags: html, angular6

Am using angular 6, but i don't know how to use *ngFor in html table looping. i need code for below attached screenshot. Also am given API response

```
{
  "result": [
    [
      {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "sno": "1",
        "name": "abc",
        "phone": "123456",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "sno": "2",
        "name": "def",
        "phone": "789456",
        "email": "def@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "sno": "3",
        "name": "ghi",
        "phone": "4561230",
        "email": "ghi@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "sno": "1",
        "name": "john",
        "phone": "4561230",
        "email": "john@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested ngFor Loop check the example below:

```
<table id="spreadsheet">
<tr *ngFor="let data of result">
    <td class="row-number-column">{{data[0].title}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let item of data">
   <tr>
   <td class="row-number-column">{{item.sno}}</td>
   <td class="row-name-column">{{item.name}}</td>
   <td class="row-name-column">{{item.phone}}</td>
    </tr></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks for your answer, i have implemented your code but got an error like this 

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "tr". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                [ERROR ->]</tr>
                           </tbody>

Comment: common man,this is because of second last line tr closing will come first then td